# Basic Form using HTML and Php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create just a basic form using Php and HTML. When I type into the fields and click submit nothing appears on the page except for "Hi,"

This is what I have for the HTML document

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Php Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  method="post" action="PHPD1.php">
<label> First Name:<input name="FName" type="text"/></label>
    <br>
<label> Last Name:<input name="LName" type="text"/></label>
    <br>
<label>Message: <textarea name="message">
         </textarea>
    </label>
    <br>
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>`
```

and for the php document I have

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>Deliverable 1</title>

</head>

<?php

// Capture the values posted to this php program from the text fields

$FName = $_POST['FName'] ;
$LName = $_POST['LName'] ;
$Message = $_POST['Message'] ;

?>

<body>
    Hi, <?php print $FName; ?>
<br>
<?php print $Message; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: change `$_POST['Message']` to `$_POST['message']`

Comment: Try putting <?php print_r($_POST); ?> at the top of your page and see if your $_POST data is getting through at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <textarea name="message">
         </textarea>
```

the name given for textarea is "message". so the same name should be used in the php page also to access the value.

instead of

```
     $Message = $_POST['Message'] ;
```

use

```
    $Message = $_POST['message'] ;
```

you have done a small mistake.
just check now.

Comment: I fixed the 'message' issue and tried the <?php print_r($_POST); ?> and I'm still not getting anything other than "Hi"

Comment: @Clueless I've tested it in my local machine and your code works with a little fixes on "message". Please make sure also to save it as `.php` instead of plain html file. Maybe that would help.